# Set a pixel distance from top of page when scrolling to element

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following jQuery code to scroll between elements on my page from a fixed navigation bar at the top which is working fine accept that some text at the top disappears behind my navigation bar. How can I modify this code so that it only scrolls to a specific distance from the top(height of my nav bar) of the page?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;
    var $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to scroll all the way to the top you can simply add the offset you need to the `scrollTop`

```
var height = //<distance to top>;
$('html, body').stop().animate({
    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top + height
}, 900, 'swing', function () {
    window.location.hash = target;
});
```

Comment: Instead op plus i'm using minus which works better but thanks for leading me in the right direction

Comment: This is working in chrome browser, but not working in latest Mozilla browser